# how can i see object data returned by node_load() method in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-6

I need to see the full object returned by node_load() method. I know we can use var_dump() method for this. but don't understand where and how to use the var_dump() method...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print the output in a drupal message (I'm using var_export() to redirect the output).

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.var_export($node, true).'</pre>');
```

Paste these lines on the first line of the function.